# How can I use Jquery .load inside a hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im new to Jquery please be gentle...
My page has a list of hidden divs marked "`.port`", in addition each of these has a specific id such as "`#test`". the divs only show after an event triggers`$(itemID).addClass('item_open');`
(the css rules then shows the div via - "

```
.port.item_open {
  visibity: visible;
```

" so that the div is shown as a fullscreen modal...)
*In order to make the page load faste*r - I wish to load the content of the **"itemID"** by replacing it from *another html* only after it has the added class of **"item_open"**.

Ive tryied using this `$( "#test.port.item_open" ).load( "items.html #test > *" );`but it didnt work...

**help me pls**
here is a test : http://aniboaz.co.il/Test.html

Comment: Try to add spaces in `#test.port.item_open`. Your statement means a `div` with id `#test` **and** class `.port` **and** class `item_open`.

Comment: but the div *should* have all three...

Comment: You are firing the load before the item has the class item_open. Either use event delegation or fire the load after the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are firing the load before the item has the class item_open. Fire the load when you add the class:

```
$("#test")
    .addClass("item_open")
    .load("items.html #test", function(){
        // callback after load, e.g. jump to the correct part
    });
```